# Saving a stream in TempData MVC3 C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have a InputStream which I save into a TempData["stream1"] during file load. I will then process this file with a button click in a different controller.

The reason why I save the InputStream in Temp Data is to access it in my next button click.

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{
  Stream stream1 = fileData.InputStream;
  TempData["stream1"] = stream1;
  return "ok";
}
```

Next I get back my stream from TempData. Button "View" will invoke the below action

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MyView(string IsAll)
{
  string html = "";
  TempData["HeaderDetailHTML"] = "";
  Stream str = (Stream)TempData["stream1"];
  if (str != null)
  {
     if (str.Length == 0)
     {
     }
     else
       html = ProcessRTFFile(str, IsAll);
  }
  TempData["CustomHTML"] = html;
  return PartialView("Widgets/MyList",null);
}
```

Now, the issue is, the above works just fine in Dev environment with asp.NET IIS dev server, but when I deploy this to IIS 7 or any server, this works for only small files with less capacity. For Larger files TempData will lose the key and value when I try to access it.

I can't figure out the reason. Any reason/solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TempData uses session as its internal store, you should try to check it on memory lose or session clear. For testing purposes you could save that file into session first and try to observe results

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just tried what you have suggested with a session variable and even with that the issue remains the same. So I guess this is related to Session. Is there a default size for a session data and a way we could adjust this in either IIS or web config? thanks..

Comment: Yes, there is. What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS 7.5 is what I use and the IDE is VS2010 Pro

Comment: Take a look at application pool -> recycling, or application pool -> advanced settings. Maybe your session is recycled because of memory